# How to prove that $\mathrm{End}_R(M)$ is a division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

The following problem baffles me a lot, which is an exercise of a lecture of module theory:

> Suppose that $M$ is an indecomposable $R$-module, where $R$ is a unital ring. If $M$ is both noetherian and artinian, and the composition factors of $M$ are not isomorphic pairwise, then $\mathrm{End}_R(M)$ is a division ring.

Since $M$ is indecomposable, for each nonvanishing $f\in\mathrm{End}_R(M)$ from the Fitting lemma it follows that $f$ is either bijective or nilpotent. Nevertheless I have no idea how the condition of composition factors can eliminate the case that $f$ is nilpotent, so I would like to ask what to do next.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What does it means "the composition factors of $M$ are not isomorphic pairwise"? Do you know something more about $R$?

Comment: @user84976 $R$ is a ring with an identity. $M$ is both noetherian and artinian and thus it has a composition series. I mean that any two composition factors of this composition series are not isomorphic.

Comment: Where did you find the problem? The condition on composition factors seems very strange.

Comment: @rschwieb Yeah I also think it very strange. This problem is an assignment of my algebra course. My professor referred us to Nathan Jacobson's Basic Algebra II for the part of module theory but I did not find any hint...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it follows immediately from $\text{im}(f)\cap \ker(f)=0$ for all $f\in \text{End}_R(M)$.  The intersection is $0$ because $M$ has pairwise nonisomorphic composition factors.

Comment: Could you please tell me why $M$ having pairwise nonisomorphic composition factors implies the kernel and image intersect trivially?

Comment: Because the composition factors of $\text{im}(f)$ and of $\ker(f)$ must be composition factors of $M$.

Comment: Ah... I guess I have understood that. But why a nilpotent endomorphism $f$ such that $\mathrm{im}(f)\cap\ker(f)=0$ must be $0$?

Comment: This intersection condition implies that every endomorhism $f$ is an automorphism on $\text{im}(f)$.

Comment: Got it. Then all these make a nice proof for that. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but when I am formulating the proof, I find it difficult to deduce that the intersection of kernel and image is trivial from the fact that their composition factors are also $M$'s. Could you kindly give me more details about this step?

Comment: Because the filtration $0 \subseteq \ker(f) \subseteq M$ can be refine.  In this refinement, the composition factors of $\ker(f)$ and of $\text{im}(f)\cong M/\ker(f)$ are present.

Comment: Oh this is quite reasonable... Now I guess I have no doubts. Thank you again! Have a nice day~